# Can i install Hyper-V on a windows 2008 active directory server

Tags: active-directory, hyper-v

I have a physical Win2008 server, std, running as first AD server in the organisation. A secondary AD server runs on a separate box in a VM.

I need to host a VM on the main Win2008 AD server, its hyper-v capable, other than the fact its probably not great practice, theres a lot of memory and processor not doing very much, is there any technical reason why I cant do it?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can run Hyper-V on a DC without issue. It's not an ideal solution as you are putting all your eggs in one basket, but technically speaking it is do-able.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any KB that prevent it. But everyone will tell you not to do it, moreover if you have a problem after with it.

Keep at least 2GB for the root partition. Put VM somewhere it can't full the partition where AD lives in (c: by default)